# 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector error

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

When I am trying to deploy a Docker image to EKS Cluster using Helm, I am getting this error:

`Warning  FailedScheduling  33s (x5 over 4m58s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.`

Here is helm chart i am using deployment.yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-chart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helm-chart.name" . }}
    {{- toYaml .Values.iamLabels | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helm
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "helm-chart.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers: 
        - name: {{ .Values.image.name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.image.containerPort }}
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: {{ .Values.image.envSecretName }}
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          livenessProbe:
            {{- toYaml .Values.livenessProbe | nindent 12 }}
          readinessProbe:
            {{- toYaml .Values.readinessProbe | nindent 12 }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

Anyone has a solution for this I am struck by long.

When i am trying to use this template i am getting above error 3 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector.

Answer (score 1):

Or your nodes are not ready and have some custom taints.
Or your helm deployment has some affinity.
Try to template your helm deployment and check that you don't have an affinity there.